# Ubuntu, Cloud-init, Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: cloud-init

Ubuntu cloud image 20.04, ESXi 8

```
#cloud-config
users:
  - name: demo
    groups: sudo
    shell: /bin/bash
    sudo: ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
    ssh_authorized_keys:
      - ssh-rsa AAAAB3Nz....
```

so far so good, but when I do

```
ssh demo@192.168.50.159
```

getting

```
demo@192.168.50.159: Permission denied (publickey).
```

What Im missing. thanks!

Comment: what does ssh -v demo@192.168.50.159 tell you? You can do -vv or -vvv to increase the debugging output.

Comment: @RobertLongson here is the log file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NcaO9ea4cOfq0JW2yVlHmn--Eh16oxX5/view?usp=sharing
thanks for your help.

Comment: your client seems to be offering a key, you'll need some debugging from the response to see why it's being rejected.

Comment: Strange issue honestly. Ive changed the user name - and is working.